# Tensorflow train speed with multiple GPU

Tags: tensorflow, time, gpu

I currently have a problem with the speed of training a new tensorflow model. Actually, I assumed that if I use more than one GPU for training, the speed of training will increase significantly. However, I found out that this is not the case. After several tests locally and in the Google Cloud I am slowly at a loss how to increase the speed significantly. Maybe someone has a hint how I can speed up the training. Currently, just over 10,000 images are trained with an image size of 628 x 628.

**My environment local:**

```
absl-py==0.11.0
astor==0.8.1
cycler==0.10.0
gast==0.4.0
grpcio==1.34.0
h5py==2.10.0
imageai==2.1.5
importlib-metadata==2.1.1
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.1.0
Markdown==3.2.2
matplotlib==3.0.3
mock==3.0.5
numpy==1.18.5
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
Pillow==7.2.0
protobuf==3.14.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
termcolor==1.1.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
zipp==1.2.0
```

Ryzen 5 3600
Nvidia 1060 (6 GB)
50 GB RAM

**My environment Google Cloud:**

Everything runs in a Docker container

```
absl-py==0.11.0
astor==0.8.1
cycler==0.10.0
gast==0.4.0
grpcio==1.34.0
h5py==2.10.0
imageai==2.1.5
importlib-metadata==2.1.1
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.1.0
Markdown==3.2.2
matplotlib==3.0.3
mock==3.0.5
numpy==1.18.5
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
Pillow==7.2.0
protobuf==3.14.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
termcolor==1.1.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
zipp==1.2.0
```

16 vCPU
60 GB RAM
4 x NVIDIA Tesla T4

**My test results for the required time per epoch:**

```
1x Nvidia 1060 with a batch size of 4 = 2,97 hours
1x Tesla T4 with a batch size of 12 = 1,19 hours
2x Tesla T4 with a batch size of 12 = 3,37 hours
2x Tesla T4 with a batch size of 24 = 3,37 hours
```

Why does it take longer to train with two Tesla T4s than with just one and why is the training time not faster with a higher batch size? I am grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the architecture of your network and therefore it is not possible to precisely answer your question.

If you remember Amdahl's law from your computer science classes, parallel processing introduces synchronization overhead.

If you network is not complex enough, training in multiple GPU's will just make it slower since the overhead of parameter update across multiple GPU's will be bigger than the speed up you are getting by having more processing power.

Comment: I currently use yolov3 with imageai. What is the possibility to make the training much faster? I would test the Nvidia A100 in the cloud next, but even that would quickly reach its limits on its own.

Answer (score -1):

I currently use yolov3 with imageai. What is the possibility to make the training much faster? I would test the Nvidia A100 in the cloud next, but even that would quickly reach its limits on its own.

Answer (score -1):

If you want very efficient model training, I suggest using Google Collab (or even better, use Google Collab Pro).

- https://colab.research.google.com/

On my local machine with a RTX 2080 I had a model train for roughly 2.5 hours/epoch, but on Google Collab, it reduced to about 30min/epoch.

Last time I checked on the open-source GitHub, multi-GPU usage is not supported, but is a feature request that may be in progress.